# あるhtmlタグについて、それを内包しているタグから見た時に何番目の位置に存在しているのか知りたい

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

例えば、`name属性がtitleであるinputタグを内包しているliタグは、ulタグ内で何番目に位置するか` という情報を取得したいとき、どのようなJavaScriptを記述すれば実現できるのか良いアイディアが出ません。

どなたかご教授いただければ幸いです。

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="text" name="title"></li>
    <li><input type="number" name="price"></li>
    <li>
        <select name="number">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

タグに `jquery` がありましたので、jQuery使用のコードで回答いたします。

```
var i = $('input[name=title]').parent('li').index();
```

これで `i` に何番目か入ることになります。 `i` は 0 から始まることに注意してください。

参考コード: http://jsdo.it/blueberrystream/hT9G （[Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20191017111040/http://jsdo.it/blueberrystream/hT9G)）

Comment: 皆様、様々なアプローチを提示していただきありがとうございました。ベストアンサーに悩みましたが、示していただいた中で KID the Euforia さんのコードの実行速度が最速であったため、こちらをベストアンサーとさせて頂きました。

Answer (score 3):

has使ったら直感的かなぁと:

```
$('li:has(input[name=title])').index();
```

Answer (score 2):

1. input 要素を取るのは、 `document.querySelector('ul>li>input[name="title"]');`
2. 要素が、親からみて何番目かは、`[].indexOf.call(NODE.parentNode.children, NODE)`

以下のようにできます:

```
// 準備: price を値に持つ input を取る
var input = document.querySelector('ul>li>input[name="price"]');
var li = input.parentNode

// その li は ul の何番目にありますか？
var count = [].indexOf.call(li.parentNode.children, li);

window.alert( count) // => 1
```

一般的なブラウザ(Chrome, Firefox 3.5+, IE 9+)であれば、 [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector) は用意されています。

**追記:**

無駄に煮詰まったので:

```
var input = document.querySelector('ul>li>input[name="price"]');
var li = input.parentNode

var i = 0; while((li = li.previousElementSibling) != null) i++;
window.alert( i) // => 1
```

jQuery は、.previousSibling を使っていますね。

Answer (score 2):

jQueryを使うのであれば、

```
$('input[name=title]').closest('li').index()
```

で良いかと